# How to Increase Text Size in CodeBlocks Output Screen?

Tags: codeblocks

I need to increase the text size of this output screen on Codeblocks. Can anyone guide me on how to achieve this? I've searched through the settings but couldn't find an option for it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJFFd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I remember from `Settings` select `Environment`, the `View` contains `Message logs' font size` that allows you to modify output screen font sizes.

Comment: thats increase the text size of the log message. but i want to increase the output screen text size

Comment: What do you mean of "output screen"? You seem to put an Image on, but I can't see it.